# Irregular shapes in Android layout

Tags: android, layout, oval

Any idea how to layout these so they shape around with click able buttons?

[image: Image of buttons in an ellipsis layout.]

Comment: You are asking, more or less, for a radial menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to achieve it, Design the layout for the imageviews and add each portion of your image into it and use selector drawable to change image in certain events

i think this way you can achieve your purpose [image]

try below layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">



    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="New Button"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button3" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
    </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="New Button"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button3" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="New Button"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hi Abhishek, I'm adding different imageview for each part but now the problem is with different screen resolution all portions are not aligning properly as i'm using margin for each portions. Please suggest me a layout how can i achieve this entire thing intact in all type of screens...

Comment: I have used buttons, but you should use imageviews, make the center image transparent in nature and try to keep a large gap from the corners of the center image

Comment: Hi Abhishek, Thanks for your answer, now i'm able to create the the layout but the problem here is plus and minus button should also be clickable so how add those individual buttons and for some of the element i'm not able to add click event.